# Does DeleteDC automatically unselect objects?

Tags: winapi

Do I always need to call SelectObject to restore the original object into a DC (and make my object available for deletion), even when I am about to delete the DC anyway...?

e.g.

```
  // Create DC
  HBITMAP hBitmap = CreateCompatibleBitmap (hDC, rect.Width(), rect.Height());
  HGDIOBJ hOldBitmap = SelectObject(hMemDC, hBitmap);


  // ... Do some other stuff with the DC

  // DO I NEED THIS LINE HERE???
  SelectObject(hMemDC, hOldBitmap);

  // Tidy up
  DeleteDC(hMemDC);
  DeleteObject(hBitmap);  // This DOES return TRUE even without the SelectObject line...
```

Will the 'DeleteDC' automatically unselect objects selected into it, so they are available for deletion once the DC is deleted?

Thanks

Comment: Sure.  That doesn't prevent your code from leaking hOldBitmap.

Comment: I'm assuming it's NULL, since I've created the DC and my hBitmap is the first (only) bitmap I've selected into it. The only reason for selecting it back into the DC is to ensure that hBitmap is NOT selected into the DC, hence can be deleted... but you're saying it's not necessary to do that. Thanks!

Comment: "I'm assuming it's NULL." Are you sure that's a safe assumption?

Comment: DCs get a default 1x1x1 bitmap when they're created. This **will** leak if you don't put it back.

Comment: @Jonathan - thanks, that is useful to know. And Jim - no, it looks like it was not a safe assumption...!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A DC does not maintain a history of selected objects.  For example, think about what happens if you were to `SelectObject()` a different font or brush multiple times while drawing something.  The DC only knows about the *current* object, not any of the previous objects.  That is why you **MUST** always use `SelectObject()` to restore any object you replace, before freeing the DC.  `DeleteDC()` will not do that restoration for you.

This is clearly stated in the documentation:

[`SelectObject` function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd162957.aspx):

> This function returns the previously selected object of the specified type. **An application should always replace a new object with the original, default object after it has finished drawing with the new object.**

[Operations on Graphic Objects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd162753.aspx):

> Each of these functions returns a handle identifying a new object. After an application retrieves a handle, it must call the SelectObject function to replace the default object. However, the application should save the handle identifying the default object and use this handle to replace the new object when it is no longer needed. **When the application finishes drawing with the new object, it must restore the default object by calling the SelectObject function and then delete the new object by calling the DeleteObject function. Failing to delete objects causes serious performance problems.**

A DC owns the objects it was originally created with.  It will accordingly free any *current* selected objects when it is freed, as it is expecting the original objects.  Failure to restore the original objects will lead to leaks and possibly other failures in your code.

If you are going to replace/restore multiple objects while drawing, consider using [`SaveDC()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd162945.aspx) and [`RestoreDC()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd162929.aspx) to simplify restoration of original objects:

[Saving, Restoring, and Resetting a Device Context](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd162946.aspx)

Comment: I'm aware that a DC doesn't keep a history, my question was more about the fact that you can't delete an object when it is still selected into a DC. The question was, if I am calling DeleteDC, will this automatically select things out of the DC for me (thus allowing me to delete them), or do I need to do it myself? But it looks like I was actually asking the question for the wrong reason - and I DO need to restore things into the DC, not so that my objects are available for deletion, but so that the DC can delete its OWN objects once I've put them back.

Comment: ... and I do USUALLY tidy up properly after myself, but I found some code in my project where the DC was being deleted without restoring the original bitmap first, and I wondered if that cause a GDI resource leak. The answer is Yes, but not for the reasons that I thought!

Answer (score 3):

I've made my own investigations on the subject. According to them, the marked answer is not accurate, at least, in this statement:

> A DC ... will accordingly free any current selected objects when it is freed, as it is expecting the original objects.

When you select a *just created* memory bitmap into a *just created* memory DC, the memory DC does not own the bitmap (at least, in the sense of memory management) - it marks it as "used" so it can't be deleted by a `DeleteObject` call (probably, by incrementing a kind of reference count for the bitmap). If you delete the memory DC first - it *will not* delete the memory bitmap: the object count returned by `GetGuiResources(GR_GDIOBJECTS)` gets decreased by 1, i.e. only for the DC itself, not by 2 (for both the DC and the bitmap). The followed `DeleteObject(hMemBitmap)` call decreases the GDI object count accordingly.

As for the "default 1x1 bitmap's leak" mentioned [in this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27422871/does-deletedc-automatically-unselect-objects#comment43303334_27422871), it seems to be wrong as well: this bitmap is not created individually for each memory DC. Instead, it's the so-called "stock bitmap" well explained by Raymond Chen: according to [his "The mysterious stock bitmap" article](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20100416-00/?p=14313), this bitmap is a singleton used by GDI for various purposes, and it's the only bitmap that can be selected into many DCs. You can't delete it or somehow use it in any way other than selecting it into a DC. Although `DeleteObject` returns TRUE on this bitmap's handle, it does not affect the GDI object count. Selecting this bitmap back to the memory DC before deleting that DC is just a kind of good habit and actually is not required: selecting it back increases its usage reference count and then deleting the DC decreases that reference count back, which results in no gain (the reference value remains the same as it was after "deselecting" the stock bitmap out of the memory DC).

I made a PoC test program and checked it in various versions of Windows (from WinXP SP3 to the latest Win10 update) - the results are pretty consistent.

To summarize:

- the answer to the original question is *"yes, it does"*
- and the answer to `// DO I NEED THIS LINE HERE???` question is *"no, you don't - on the condition that you are sure that the old bitmap's handle is the stock bitmap's handle"*

Comment: This would explain the examples on MSDN that do not follow their own advice about restoring original bitmap handles! (For example, the code under the section "Example of a Clipboard Viewer" on [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dataxchg/using-the-clipboard).)

Comment: Wait, does that mean if you use `DeleteObject` to delete the bitmap before deleting the DC it is selected into, it will delete the bitmap as soon as you delete the DC but not before?

Comment: @JoshuaPerrett, I did not investigate this scenario in details but, AFAIR, `DeleteObject` does nothing for the object currently selected into a DC. There's another great article by Raymond Chen devoted to the subject: ["What are the dire consequences of not selecting objects out of my DC?"](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20130306-00/?p=5043) - hope it explains the details better.